# Get return address from IRQ handler?

Tags: assembly, x86

How can I peek the return value from a PIT IRQ handler in 32 bit protected mode (x86 obviously)? I think I could just do it like, I am not completely sure.

```
pop eax ; pop last thing from stack
mov dword return_address,eax
push eax
iret
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would read the right item from the stack, but if you do it this way, you will corrupt `eax`.

A proper ISR, by the end of its execution, must have all used registers restored to the state they were in when the ISR started.

Another thing to note... `return_address` is going to be referenced (implicitly) through a segment register (here, `ds`). This is OK if `ds` is always the same in the ISR and the code that the ISR interrupts. If, however, the interrupted code changes `ds`, the ISR must save `ds` at its beginning, set it to the proper selector value, use it and then restore it. If you don't do this, that `mov` instruction may corrupt memory or cause an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Something more like

```
push eax
push ds
mov eax,cs:saved_ds
mov ds,eax
mov eax,[esp+8]
mov return_address,eax
pop ds
pop eax
iret
```

would preserve eax and could handle arbitrary segment values. It requires you to save the 'ds' segment register in `saved_ds` before the above ISR runs. It uses the `cs` register to access it - most (all?) platforms have the base of cs equal to the base of ds and have cs readable.

Usually, an ISR has to acknowledge the IRQ (is your code a software interrupt hook?). Your code isn't showing it so I figured your code fragment in the question was just a stripped down version of the real code.